# Trouble with new Ubuntu 12.04 install

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

I had Ubuntu 13.04 in a dual boot setup with my Windows XP, but it didn't work properly, so I thought it would be good to install the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version, but now this one doesn't work at all. Is it because Ubuntu 12.04 was installed after Ubuntu 13.04, or is there another problem?

What must I do to get Ubuntu 12.04 properly installed? While installing, the Ubuntu installer asked me to delete the 13.04 version and reinstall the 12.04. I agreed, was this wrong?

For my kids I need to have both Windows XP and Ubuntu. I just want to have a PC that doesn't break down all the time.

Comment: I'd suggest you format the partition where Ubuntu is and repeat the process from the beginning.

Comment: As an aside: Windows XP continues to remain in [extended support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/) until [April of next year](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/lifecycle). Windows XP will receive updates to fix newly discovered security vulnerabilities [until then, but not after](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help) (so at that point you should discontinue using it, if you still are). See [this blurb](https://support.microsoft.com/gp/msl-windows-xp-office) and [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/endofsupport.aspx) for more info.

Comment: You said 12.04 "doesn't work at all." Can you be more specific? What happens, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a manual format?
During the installation of Ubuntu 12.04, delete every partition except for the window's partition. (It will either be an NTFS or a FAT32 type.) Depending on your computer, add at least a 1GB SWAP-type partition and add the rest of the free space as an Ext4 and choose to mount it as "/". That way you will be starting from scratch and it will keep your XP install. For more information, look here: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-12-04-LTS-266201.shtml and look under 4: Something else (Advanced)
Do remember to be careful not to remove your partition containing XP.